# pattern matcing of 3rd column in file1 with first column in file2

Tags: awk

I tried `Awk` as

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA");}'


cat f1.txt  
FOO,LONDON,45,789  
GOO,US,46,9876

cat f2.txt  
45,ONE  
47,SECOND
```

Result like

```
FOO,LONDON,45,789,ONE  
GOO,US,46,9876,NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print (($3 in a) ? $0","a[$3] : $0",NA");}' f2 f1
```

(OR)

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$(NF+1)=($3 in a)?a[$3]:"NA"}1' OFS=, f2 f1
```

Some issues are:

- `a[$1]=$1` - Should be `a[$1]=$2`
- `($1 in a)` - Should be `($3 in a)`

Comment: how it compares ?

Comment: @sam_84, `($3 in a)` - This one does that. `$3` of `f1` is comparing against an array (`a`) of `$1` from `f2`.

Comment: How it prints the column3 from file2 and how print additional columns from file2